# Apply method with curly braces

Tags: scala

Why this works:

```
  List(
   "string", "string2"
  )
```

But this doesn't?

```
  List{
   "string", "string2"
  }
```

Compilation error: `;' expected but ',' found.`

But for my own object with apply method there:

```
object Dictionary {    
  ...    
  private[dictionary] def apply(words: List[Word]) = {
    ...
  }
}

Dictionary { // curly braces works fine
  List ( // but here, for List - I can Not use curly braces
    "hello", "hello2" 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canonical answer on braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/1296806) and [a supplement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13873899/1296806).

[The official glossary](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#block) helpfully calls a block an encapsulation of side effects and a result value.

A [few opinions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/VFZqDT8lxhE/Wqhuz8yepBQJ) were recently expressed on the ML about braces and their non-pointy cousins.

Perhaps it is unhelpful to think of parens and braces as somehow interchangeable in some contexts.

It is easier to think in terms of exprs and blocks, and in this case, function args can be either comma-separated exprs or a block.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the comma -- you can only have a comma separated argument list when using parentheses.

You will find that

```
List {
    3
}
```

works just fine.

Comment: You have an absolutely fantastic name!