# Scala: how to destructure a basic map entry

Tags: scala, dictionary

Here is a  vanilla scala map:

```
scala> val m = Map( 'a'-> '1', 'b' -> 2)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,AnyVal] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)
```

The Map iterator() method returns a tuple representing the (key,value). So if we want to see, say, just the values of the map we can do this:

```
scala> m.map( a => a._2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[AnyVal] = List(1, 2)
```

But how do we destructure the map entry ? The following does not work:

```
scala> m.map( (a,b) =>  b)
<console>:10: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
              m.map( (a,b) =>  b)
                       ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use pattern matching:

```
m.map{ case (a, b) =>  b}
```

Map entry is just a `Tuple2`.

Comment: ur probably on the right track but there is a syntax error:    console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression

Comment: Need different brackets. `m.map{ case (a, b) =>  b}`

Comment: @kigyo BTW why does this need brace instead of parens?

Comment: @javadba: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048664/confusing-scala-higher-order-function-call-syntax/18051129#18051129). It should be a `BlockExpr` to create a `PartialFunction`.

Comment: @javadba because it's a partial function. It is only defined on elements that can be matched to (a,b). Since all elements in a map have the structure (a,b) it is defined for all elements in the map.

Comment: btw, this is not a `PartialFunction`, just an anonymous pattern match

Comment: @sschaef: Thank you! I was sure that `PartialFunction` is created here.

Comment: @sschaef  Would you either describe or point to a doc explaining how  "anonymous pattern match" and PartialFunction are related? thx

Comment: @javadba They stand in relation in so far that you have to use pattern matching to match the input a `PartialFunction` takes, that's why a lot of people assume that the occurrence of `{ case ... }` is a `PartialFunction`.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you don't want to write the `case {...}` syntax:

```
scala> import Function.{ tupled => $ }
import Function.{tupled=>$}

scala> Map(1 -> "a") map $((a,b) => b)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(a)

scala> Map(1 -> "a") map $((a,b) => a -> s"$b!")
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a!)
```