# Scala compiler says "error: identifier expected but integer literal found." for () not {}

Tags: scala

Why does the Scala `2.11.0-M3` compiler give me `error: identifier expected but integer literal found.` when the round brackets `()` are used while it compiles fine with curly brackets `{}`?

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val s = "this is a string"
s: String = this is a string

scala> s.toList map (c:Char => 1)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
       s.toList map (c:Char => 1)
                               ^

scala> s.toList map {c:Char => 1}
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Somehow it compiles fine with the round brackets as well when the left-hand side of the anonymous function is within another pair of the round brackets. Why?

```
scala> s.toList map ((c:Char) => 1)
res8: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: More in the parens vs braces wars: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/1296806  but ignore the answer about "inferring braces."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write

{ i: Int => 2 * i }

the braces are a block, and the thing inside is the result expression of the block.

The syntax is [the ResultExpr here](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L158). Note that a type is allowed after the param name, as above.

That's different from [an Expr](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L114) where it is not.

Here's an example of the difference:

```
scala> val is = List(1,2,3)
is: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

The first statement in block has a function literal, an Expr requiring parens if we specify the type. The last statement is the result expression of the block, and no parens are required:

```
scala> is map { val f = (i: Int) => 2*i; i: Int => 2*f(i) }
res0: List[Int] = List(4, 8, 12)
```

Sometimes you don't need to specify the type because it is inferred from the expected type, and with no type in the Expr, you can omit the parens:

```
scala> is map { val f: Int=>Int = i => 2*i; i: Int => 2*f(i) }
```

The [Bindings](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L207) in these productions (in the spec) is your ordinary list of params in parens, which maybe have types. With more than one param, you have to supply parens:

```
scala> is reduce { val f = (i:Int,j:Int) => i+j; (i:Int,j:Int) => 2*f(i,j) }
res2: Int = 18
```

Sometimes you'll see a big block of code as an argument to a function. That's a big function  literal as the result expression of a block, which is why you see the parameter sitting out in front, with no parens or braces:

```
scala> is map { i =>  val j = 2 * i; /* lots of LOC */ ; j }
res7: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

That is different from the following code, which is block of many lines of code with the function literal at the very end.  The function just returns `j`, or 2:

```
scala> is map { val j = 2; /* lots of LOC */ ; _ => j }
res8: List[Int] = List(2, 2, 2)
```

So we know that you can't write the following:

```
scala> is map (is: Int => 2)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
       is map (is: Int => 2)
                          ^
```

What sort of identifier would be meaningful in this context?  How about:

```
scala> is map (is: Int => Int)
```

which yields the delightful result (spoiler alert):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

This works:

```
scala> val js = List(0,1,2)
js: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2)

scala> js map (js: Int => Int)
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2)
```

The `js` in parens is just a value, obviously, not a param, and the type is a type ascription.  The value can be a post-fix expression, so this works (or rather, compiles with a feature warning about the post-fix operator syntax):

```
scala> js map (js init: Int => Int)
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

More explanation at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13873899/1296806

There is a category of confusion caused by thinking that parens and curly braces are somehow exchangeable.  But I found it clarifying to see braces as `BlockExprs`, which is what they are. Then it's easier to remember, for instance, that when you use braces in a function application, there is no magic: you've simply supplied a [block](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L149).

A block is a bunch of side-effecting statements followed by a result statement.  That's obvious for functional programmers, perhaps.  But it clarifies that the last thing in your braces is a `ResultExpr`.

(Footnote: braces for class bodies are different, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

When you write an expression `c:Char => 1`, Scala compiler treats it as `c:(Char => 1)`, that is, a function variable `c` with type `Char => 1`. However, `1` is not a valid type (or type variable), so Scala compiler complains. So you need to write `s.toList map ((c:Char) => 1)` to help the compiler out of the type association.

`{c:Char => 1}` creates a function literal, that is, a function that accepts a char and returns 1. So

```
s.toList map {c:Char => 1}
```

is the same as

```
s.toList map({c:Char => 1})

// or
val fn = {c: Char => 1}
s.toList map fn
```

<del>However, it seems that Scala doesn't have special specification for the `{c:Char => blabla}` form for creating function literals.</del>

<del>I think it is because that there is `{some_var: SomeType => *Class Definition* }` form in class definition to reference `this` with `some_var` and add lower bound of the type of `this`. This causes the Scala lexer to treat a single typed parameter after `{` to be formal parameter and treat the statements after `=>` to be actual body. Note that you ***CANNOT*** create a function with 2 parameters like this `{c: Char, d:Char => 1}`.</del>

**UPDATE**: As commented by *som-snytt*, it is result expression that causes the brace version to be evaluated to a function result.

Comment: I can see why you speculate about the braces as you do, but it's actually not hard to look at the spec, cf my answer.

Comment: Your opening statement is still misleading or imprecise. (Do I need parens? Are braces part of anon function syntax?) Probably the best suggestion is just to lose the type because it's inferred. In fact, http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#function_values

Answer (score 1):

I've digged into [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for Scala 2.9, and found out that part 6.23 describes how anonymous function have to be defined:

```
Expr ::= (Bindings | [‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘=>’ Expr
ResultExpr ::= (Bindings | ([‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘:’ CompoundType) ‘=>’ Block
Bindings ::= ‘(’ Binding {‘,’ Binding} ‘)’
Binding ::= (id | ‘_’) [‘:’ Type]
```

As you can see `Bindings` requires to be placed inside two surrounding parenthesis. So if your anonymous function defines the type of the parameter, it **has** to be defined in this way:

```
(c:Char) => 1
```

And the call to map should look like that:

```
s.toList map((c:Char) => 1)
```

Also in the same part of reference documentation you can find:

> If an anonymous function (x: T) => e with a single typed parameter
>   appears as the result expression of a block, it can be abbreviated to
>   x: T => e.

So it says that if anonymous function is defied as last expression in a code block, and has exacly one parameter, you can use abbreviated syntax to define anonymous function - without parenthesis. So, in your case, you can write `c:Char => 1` but only when you place it inside a code block `{c:Char => 1}`. And you can call map function this way:

```
s.toList map({c:Char => 1})
```

or with abbreviated syntax without parenthesis:

```
s.toList map {c:Char => 1}
```

On the other hand, when we look back at the anonymous function specification:

```
Expr ::= (Bindings | [‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘=>’ Expr
```

We can see that we can define your anonymous function, if we don't want to specify argument type, without parameter binding in those two ways:

```
s.toList map (c => 1)
// or
s.toList map (_ => 1)
```

---

Also, this is summarized in changelog at the end of the documentation (Changes in Version 2.1.7 (19-Jul-2006)):

Closure Syntax

The syntax of closures has been slightly restricted (§6.23). The form

```
x: T => E
```

is valid only when enclosed in braces, i.e.
`{ x: T => E }`. The following is illegal, because it might be read as the value x typed with the type T => E:

```
val f = x: T => E
```

Legal alternatives are:

```
val f = { x: T => E }
val f = (x: T) => E
```