# Do I need a trailing semicolon to disambiguate this code?

Tags: scala

If I omit the semicolon, this code doesn't compile.

```
def checkRadioButton(xml: DslBuilder): String => XmlTree = {
    val inputs = top(xml).\\*(hasLocalNameX("input"));
    { (buttonValue: String) =>
      // code omitted
    }
}
```

My guess is that, without the semicolon, scalac thinks that the partial function is another argument to the `\\*` method, instead of the return value. (It isn't actually a partial function, by the way, it's a total function.)

Can I do without the semicolon here? I've never had to use a semicolon at the end of a line before in Scala.

Comment: What is the compile error? And just out of curiosity: Does the ``\\*`` method take any second or implicit parameters?

Comment: Have you tried to use `locally { ... }` to separate the `val` line and the block ?

Comment: The compilation error is `scales.xml.XPath[List[scales.utils.Path[scales.xml.XmlItem,scales.xml.Elem,[T]scales.utils.ImmutableArrayProxy[T]]]] does not take parameters`, and no, it doesn't take any second or implicit parameters. There are some overloaded methods with the same name, but they don't either.

Comment: @Beryllium that also doesn't compile.

Comment: @Robin Green Have you tried to assign the result of the block to a `val` and return that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d write it like this instead:

```
def checkRadioButton(xml: DslBuilder): String => XmlTree = {
    val inputs = top(xml).\\*(hasLocalNameX("input"));
    (buttonValue: String) => { // <-- changed position of {
      // code omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: That can be simpler, see my answer. You can send the braces back to the parts bin and help keep la Suisse sweet.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a second newline, which apparently is equivalent to the semicolon.

Still, I'm not entirely happy with this, as it seems fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplification, explanation, and beautification.

Simplified,

```
scala> def f: String => String = {
     | val i = 7
     | { (x: String) =>
     |   "y"
     | }
     | }
<console>:9: error: Int(7) does not take parameters
       { (x: String) =>
       ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String => String
       }
       ^
```

This fails because the newline after the `7` is not taken as a semicolon, for the reason that it might be a function application; you might want a DSL where the brace is on the next line.  [Here is the little `nl` in the syntax of an arg with braces.](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/v2.10.2/documentation/src/reference/SyntaxSummary.tex#L148)

Newline handling is described in 1.2 of the spec; a few spots like this one, where a single `nl` is accepted, are mentioned at the end of the section.

(Two newlines doesn't work, which is why that also fixes your problem.)

Notice that a `nl` is not accepted in front of a paren, so the following works (though with only parens, you get only one expression for your function literal):

```
scala> def g: String => String = {
     | val i = 7
     | ( (x: String) =>
     |   "y"
     | )
     | }
g: String => String
```

In fact, the best edit for the problem code is not more braces but fewer:

```
scala> def f: String => String = {
     | val i = 7
     | x: String =>
     | "y"
     | }
f: String => String
```

[The reason for this nice syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13873899/1296806) is that your method body is already a block expression, and when the result expression of a block is a function literal, you can simplify.

The type of `x` is also redundant.

```
scala> def f: String => String = {
     | val i = 7
     | x =>
     | val a = "a"
     | val b = "b"
     | a + i + x + b
     | }
f: String => String
```

And not surprisingly:

```
scala> def f: (String, Int) => String = {
     | val i = 7
     | (x, j) =>
     | x + (i + j)
     | }
f: (String, Int) => String

scala> f("bob",70)
res0: String = bob77
```