# The semicolon inference doesn't work when an assignment statement is followed by curly braces in Scala?

Tags: scala

At http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html#7.7,
I see the following code

```scala
val a = 1;
{
  val a = 2
  println(a)
}
println(a)
```

where it says that the semicolon is required here, but why?

From the rule at http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html#4.2 ,
I think the semicolon should be auto added since

1. `val a = 1` can be a legal statement.
2. The next line begins with `{`, which I think can start a legal statement. (Since there's no compile error if I add the semicolon and separate the first two lines into two statements.)
3. `val a = 1` is not in parentheses or brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it would be a legal call to `apply`:

```
implicit class RichInt(i: Int) {
  def apply(thunk: => Unit) = 33
}

val a = 1
{
  val a = 2
  println(a)
}
println(a)  // 33 !
```

`1 { ... }` is short for `1.apply {...}`. Now `apply` is not defined for an `Int` by default, but as the implicit enrichment shows, it is perfectly possible.

---

**Edit**: The semicolon inference conditions are described in '§1.2 Newline Characters' of the [Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf). The inferred semicolon is called 'special token "`nl`"' in that text.

In general, three rules are given (summarised ex-negativo [in this blog entry](http://jittakal.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/scala-rules-of-semicolon-inference.html)), and in your example they are all satisfied. The reason that the semicolon is still not inferred is given further down in the text.

> The Scala grammar ... contains productions where optional `nl` tokens, but not semicolons, are accepted. This has the effect that a newline in one of these positions does not [!] terminate an expression or statement.

The relevant case of such an extra rule is the following:

> A single new line token is accepted
>   – in front of an opening brace “{”, if that brace is a legal continuation of the current statement or expression ...

Example 1.2.2 shows the case of anonymous an subclass which I had referred to in the comment.

Comment: Dose it means that `.apply` is always inserted before the semicolon inference take place?

Comment: Semicolon inference works by looking at the beginning of the next line. If that constitutes a valid method call, semicolon is _not_ inferred (but the method call consumed). E.g. `"schoko"\n.reverse`, or `"schoko"\n.apply(1)`. Since `apply` is often used to introduce custom control structure like methods, allowing the next line to start with an open curly brace is probably a good thing. On the other hand, using parentheses won't work.

Comment: Think also about this case: `new Foo { def bar = 33 }`, depending on your style preference you might want to have a line break before the open curly brace, too. In that case, Scala will not infer `apply` but assume you are creating an anonymous sub class (which makes the most sense). Therefore, if you want to introduce a curly braces block on its own—for example, to isolate local variables—, you should always make sure that you have a blank line preceding it (or use semicolon, but I think the blank line is nicer).

Comment: @pishen another example http://stackoverflow.com/a/18159362/1296806 . I think it's useful to review the few `nl` cases cited here. It seems like trivia but actually frees the mind a bit.

Comment: Extra blank line is good suggestion.  Also, use `locally` from `Predef` for local stuff.

Comment: `locally`, hmmm, always new things to discover even after years :)