# Range.foreach executes in weird order

Tags: scala

I'm a total Scala newbie and at a loss as to what is going on here:

```scala
(1 to 2) foreach {
  println("+")
  v => { println(v) }
  println("-")
}
```

Why does this print the following?

```
+
1
-
2
-
```

I think it has something to do with an instance being created implicitly and the body being executed as the constructor, which would explain the `+` being printed once. But that doesn't explain why the `-` is printed after each loop.

I'm sorry if this is a silly question. This just keeps nagging me. Debug execution inside Eclipse didn't reveal anything enlightening either.

And to add to the question: Why is this valid? I've understood that `foreach` should accept one parameter, a function, which receives an `Int` and returns, umm.. something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is interpreting your code like so:

```
(1 to 2) foreach {
  println("+")
  v => {{ println(v) }
    println("-")
  }
}
```

To clarify - `foreach` takes a single argument of the type being iterated over (so, in this case an `Int`) and runs the function passed in as an argument to it over that value. In this case, the first `println` is invoked during the construction of said function. The compiler has to then interpret the rest of the function as something of the form:

```
v: Int => Unit
```

which is exactly what it does in your case, the fact that you put an extra set of braces does not change it, you could just as easily have done:

```
(1 to 2) foreach {
  println("+")
  v => println(v)
    println("-")
}
```

Comment: God of programming help me if it does. A link to the specification saying so would be helpful.

Comment: @Gima, §6.11 of the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) deals with blocks. I don't see how else the compiler could interpret your code without considering everything after `v =>` as a single block

Comment: To clarify a bit more, `foreach` doesn't "take a single argument of the type being iterated over", it takes a function which "takes a single argument" etc.

Comment: Explaining why braces are unnecessary when a function literal is the result expression of a block: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13873899/1296806